# Disallowing duplicate variable names in different scopes in VB6

Tags: variables, vb6, scope, duplicates, declaration

When I have a variable declared globally, I can re-use the same variable-name at function-level, without the compiler complaining about it.

Is there some way to disable this (similar to Option Explicit)?

Comment: Adhere to some naming schema then you wont have this kind of problems. Or even better, don't use global variables (though they sometimes come in handy, they usually lead to bad structure later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not.

The operation is perfectly valid and you can still access both by fully qualifying the reference, but by default it will try and access the closest in scope.